# How can I restore Chapter page numbers in minitoc with memoir?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, memoir, minitoc

Here's my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\doparttoc
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{The Only Part}
\parttoc
\chapter{The Only Chapter}
\section{The Only Section}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Everything appears to render fine, except that the parttoc entry for the chapter has no page number (while the entry for the section does).

If I use the report class, with no other changes, the chapter page number reappears.
The main toc appears normal in both cases.

I *am* considering solving this by turning off all  page numbers in the parttoc, but I'd like the option of keeping them, with the chapter page numbers too.

---

I have successfully tested, and accepted, @Stefan Kottwitz' solution with minitoc v60 and memoir v3.6g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, `\ptcpagenumbers` should fix it. But there are known incompatibilities between certain versions of minitoc and memoir, though the minitoc author tries to keep that minimal.

I could reproduce your problem with minitoc v60 and memoir v3.6d. I read in minitoc.sty which internal macro is used. I defined such that it worked. This is the fix, just add it to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\ptc@pgno\null
\makeatother
```

As known, such internal macros might change in future versions.

Comment: Thank you. Your valuable warning on the last line is duly noted (:-)